# Is there a row alternative for <th> in HTML?

Tags: html

So I want to render a timetable in HTML, such that each column has a title (the day) and each row has a title (the time). I've just found out that [you can only use `<th>` for titles in the `<thead>` section](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_th.asp), and I can't find an alternative for creating titles for the rows. I'm currently using the `<th>`s and their id's to give headers to the timetable entries. The values of the header are then used to enter data into those cells. So is there any way to add titles to rows so I can preserve this behaviour?

Comment: you are using css right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've just found out that you can only use `<th>` for titles in the `<thead>` section,

- That isn't true (the specification [has an example to the contrary](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.1))
- [W3Schools is not a good resource](http://w3fools.com/)
- The page you link to does not, as far as I can see, claim that

If a cell is a header, then use a `<th>` — anywhere in a table. If it is a header for a row or a column, use a `scope` attribute. If the relationship is more complicated, use a `headers` attribute on the `<td>` elements for which it is a header.

Also note the [comment in the DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6) that says: *TH is for headers, TD for data, but for cells acting as both use TD*

Comment: Just use `<th scope="row"></th>` for a header that labels a row. Read more in the specifications (html4 and html5).

Comment: @FrancisAvila What advantage is there in defining the scope? Is it treated as a CSS class/id ?

Comment: You make the semantic meaning of the `th` clear. Aside from its own benefit, you can use it as a styling hook and it can be understood by assistive devices or machine parsers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can have `<th>` in any row:

I just ran this through the validator and it seems fine: http://validator.w3.org/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    table,th,td{border:1px inset #000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Title</th><th>Title</th><th>Title</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Title</th><td>content</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Title</th><td>content</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Title</th><td>content</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Then again it may be some funky HTML5 nonsense; but no one says you have to use HTML5!

You can see this page here if you want: http://jsbin.com/ilazul

Validated here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Filazul

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified in my question that I'm using HTML5. I know it's not required, but it does give me some nice functionality that I'm making use of. Thanks for your answer though, at least I know that about HTML4 :)